# Substitute: previous match with confirm

Tags: key-bindings, command-line, substitute, cursor-movement

If I do a replace like this:

```
:%s/May/June/gc
```

afterward I keep hitting `y` or `n` as needed. But sometimes it hit `n` on
accident and need to go back. I read that you can use `N` for this purpose, but
it seems what you actually have to do is:

```
q
N
:,$s/May/June/gc
```

Is that the case, or is a better option available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is something like this:

`/MAY`
<kbd>Enter</kbd>
`cgn`
`JUNE`
<kbd>Esc</kbd>

Then use `n` to go forward, or `N` to go back, and `.` to replace.